# Images (and css) randomly fails to load with no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, python, css, networking, uwsgi

I have a simple Flask+SQLite app that lives on Digital Ocean droplet and is served by uWSGI (I'll add NGINX when I this issue is solved).

Every time that I load a page, some images fail to load the first time. It's totally random which images and when they fail to load. To overcome this issue, I've made a reloader function that detects the failed images and reload them until they're loaded.
That produces network log like this one:

[image]

You can see that for example, `icon_order_history.svg` failed to load twice, and then successfully loaded the third time.

It's actually all fine if images don't load, I don't really mind it that much, but sometimes css fails to load and results in a situation like this one:

[image]

I don't know what could cause this, I don't think it's a bad internet connection since it also happens on localhost.

Here's the reloader function:

```js
function imageRetry(e) {
    setTimeout(reloadImg, 1000, e);
}
function reloadImg(e) {
    var source = e.src;
    e.src = source;
}
```

Any help is welcome, also feel free to ask me any questions/request more info.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not being able to solve the issue for a couple of days. I've decided to redeploy everything using a slightly different method.
That solved the issue but the reason behind slow/random load fails stays unknown.